# loop through firebase real time database to get only one value for matching purposes

Tags: arrays, json, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this app that registers the personal info of a patient and store it as Json Format on the database on the following format :

```
Patients {
            patient id e.g.123456789 {
                                       name:
                                       email:
                                       password:
                                       bloodPressureReading {

                                               10:37:13AM29Oct-2019:{
                                                                     dia:34
                                                                     prp:45 
                                                                     sys:12
                                                                     }
                                                              }
                                     }


          }
```

I'm at the login page, and I need from the user to enter both his id and password for a simple login procedure. However, I don't know how to retrieve the password value from the firebase realtime database.

P.S. I don't want to use the firebase authentication service

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
databasePatients.child("\"Patients\"").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                             @Override
                                                             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                                                 //showData(dataSnapshot);

                                                                 //old Code
                                                                 /*
                                                                 for(DataSnapshot uniqueKeySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                                                     //Loop 1 to go through all the child nodes of users
                                                                     for(DataSnapshot booksSnapshot : uniqueKeySnapshot.child("123456789").getChildren()){
                                                                         //loop 2 to go through all the child nodes of books node
                                                                         //String bookskey = booksSnapshot.getKey();
                                                                         //String password = booksSnapshot.getValue();
                                                                     }
                                                                 }
                                                             }*/
```

I tried this code also, It doesn't return any result although the id and password are corrects

Button testbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

```
    // To move to register page
    testbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty( (testid.getText().toString().trim()))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter id to search for!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else
            {
               Query query = databasePatients.child("Patients").orderByChild("id").equalTo(testid.getText().toString().trim());
                //Query query = databasePatients.child("Patients").child("123456789").orderByChild("id").equalTo(testid.getText().toString().trim());
                        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Context context = getContext();
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        // dataSnapshot is the "issue" node with all children with id 0

                        for (DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            // do something with the individual "issues"
                            patients usersBean = user.getValue(patients.class);

                            if (usersBean.password.equals(txvPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                                                                 @Override
                                                                 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                                 }
                                                             });
```

I also tried the code in
[Login using email stored in firebase realtime database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136779/login-using-email-stored-in-firebase-realtime-database?rq=1)
 ,but I don't know why (dataSnapshot.exists()) return false .

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Comment: What you are proposing sounds like a potentially risky and insecure approach. Without Firebase Authentication, you have no real way to use security rules to secure your data. To be able to "loop through" passwords from the client would mean they are essentially world-readable and your app would be vulnerable to all kinds of attacks. I'd strongly recommend you take a different approach and either use Firebase Auth or use custom tokens.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I need to do so for a special purpose. Can you help me find out how?

Comment: Where you're going, I cannot follow :)

Comment: I mean that I understand the risk, but I don't want to change the method and I still want to find out why the last code isn't working =)